# NameError: name 'parameter' is not defined

Tags: python

So I am having this problem to my code. It says:

> "NameError: name 'token' is not defined.

I am writing a token generator, (like a password generator) and I made a function called `buy_tokens(token)`. Even after the function, it does not read the parameter that is passed in the `buy_token` function. To understand better, read the code:

```
from random import randint
import string
import time
import random
import os

print("Tokens are saved to your tokens.txt file. \n \n \n")



# Layer 2(2)-3: Open and write token in file, (def(openfile function))
def openfile(token):
    save_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop"
    file_name = "tokens.txt"
    full_name = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
    print(full_name)
    file1 = open(full_name, "w")
    file1.write(str(token))
    file1.close()


# Layer 2(2): Generate tokens
def token_generator() -> object:
    print("Welcome to a token generator, for free. Coded by Thomas.")
    token_length = int(input("\nEnter the length of the token you want to generate:   \n"))
    token_word = input("Enter the word you want your token to include so that you can remember it: (Unnecessary)   \n")
    print("Generating token.......")
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 60))
    print("\nToken is used to generate random string for profile confusion. Token saved in your tokens.txt file.: \n")
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation

    all = lower + upper + num + symbols

    temp = random.sample(all, token_length)
    token = "".join(temp)

    all = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

    generated_token = "".join(random.sample(all, token_length))
    print(token + token_word)
    return openfile(str(token))


# Layer 2(1): Buy tokens
def buy_tokens(token):
    total_dirtycoins = 150
    print("Welcome to out token store. Buy tokens. Each token costs 50 dirtycoins. You currently have 150 dirtycoins")
    print("Buy small token: 50 DC (1).\n Buy medium token: 100 DC (2).\n Buy Big token: 150 DC (3).")
    selection_mode = input("Type '1' for option one. '2' for option 2 and '3' for option 3.:\n Answer:       ")
    if selection_mode == "1":
        total_dirtycoins -= 50
        print("You bought a small token. Token stored in tokens.txt folder in your desktop")
        print(f"You have {total_dirtycoins} tokens left.")
        return openfile(token)
    elif selection_mode == "2":
        total_dirtycoins -= 100
        print("You bought a medium token. Token stored in tokens.txt folder in your desktop")
        print(f"You have {total_dirtycoins} tokens left.")
        return openfile(token)
    elif selection_mode == "3":
        total_dirtycoins -= 150
        print("You bought a big token. Token stored in tokens.txt folder in your desktop")
        print(f"You have {total_dirtycoins} tokens left.")
        return openfile(token)
    else:
        print("Could not complete purchase. Permission denied. Error {0}")


# Layer 1: Select market

select_market = input("Select markets: Option 1: Generate tokens. Option 2: Buy tokens.\n")
if select_market == "1":
    token_generator()

elif select_market == "2":
    buy_tokens(token)

else:
    print("No market found, Permission denied.")
```

I know I have some errors but I want to fix them step by step. First is the error as i mentioned called `NameError` and second is that it prints the function and not the token that generated. I do not understand this because in the first function called `generate_token`, it prints the generated token, and when i run the function `buy_tokens(token)` it prints the function. Example:
`<function token_generator at 0x000001380F489E50>`. Why does this happen at the second function and why do I get the name error? Thank you for your time.

Comment: ```token``` are not defined. What is the value of ```token```?

Comment: @Sujay what do you mean?

Comment: ```token``` is a parameter which is used inside the function only. When you pass ```token```, python fetches the value of ```token```. But it doesn't know what is the value, because you never assigned it. So an error

Comment: @Sujay So what do i do?

Comment: define ```token```, something?

Comment: @Sujay Yes, it gives the option to define token. Let's say i fixed it and it prints to the tokens.txt file. But it prints the function, and i do not have the same problem with the first function (generate_token). What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the way you generate a token, you should use the secrets module in python to generate tokens and whatnot used for cryptographical purposes like so:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> secrets.token_hex(16)
'8f42a73054b1749f8f58848be5e6502c'
```

This is a better way to do it,:

```
import secrets
def token_generator() -> object:
    print("Welcome to a token generator, for free. Coded by Thomas.")
    token_length = int(input("\nEnter the length of the token you want to generate:   \n"))
    print("Generating token.......")
    print("\nToken is used to generate random string for profile confusion. Token saved in your tokens.txt file.: \n")

    generated_token = secrets.token_hex(token_length)
    print(generated_token)
    return openfile(str(generated_token))
```

So, on my machine, option 1 works as intended, for option 2 which is buy_tokens, you are passing an object called 'token' but you haven't generated one yet, so you first have to generate a token to pass it on to buy_tokens() function. you can achieve it by using the same function above, so for option 2, just call the token_generator first or to use an already made token you can read the prvsly made file like this:

```
elif select_market == "2":
    token_generator()
    f = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\tokens.txt", "r")
    token = f.read()
    f.close()
    buy_tokens(token)
```

Now the entire code works as you intended it to. Here is the entire code summary:

```
import secrets
import os

print("Tokens are saved to your tokens.txt file. \n \n \n")



# Layer 2(2)-3: Open and write token in file, (def(openfile function))
def openfile(token):
    save_path = r"C:\Users\mayan\Desktop"
    file_name = "tokens.txt"
    full_name = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
    print(full_name)
    file1 = open(full_name, "w")
    file1.write(str(token))
    file1.close()


def token_generator() -> object:
    print("Welcome to a token generator, for free. Coded by Thomas.")
    token_length = int(input("\nEnter the length of the token you want to generate:   \n"))
    print("Generating token.......")
    print("\nToken is used to generate random string for profile confusion. Token saved in your tokens.txt file.: \n")

    generated_token = secrets.token_hex(token_length)
    print(generated_token)
    return openfile(str(generated_token))


# Layer 2(1): Buy tokens
def buy_tokens(token):
    total_dirtycoins = 150
    print("Welcome to out token store. Buy tokens. Each token costs 50 dirtycoins. You currently have 150 dirtycoins")
    print("Buy small token: 50 DC (1).\n Buy medium token: 100 DC (2).\n Buy Big token: 150 DC (3).")
    selection_mode = input("Type '1' for option one. '2' for option 2 and '3' for option 3.:\n Answer:       ")
    if selection_mode == "1":
        total_dirtycoins -= 50
        print("You bought a small token. Token stored in tokens.txt folder in your desktop")
        print(f"You have {total_dirtycoins} tokens left.")
        return openfile(token)
    elif selection_mode == "2":
        total_dirtycoins -= 100
        print("You bought a medium token. Token stored in tokens.txt folder in your desktop")
        print(f"You have {total_dirtycoins} tokens left.")
        return openfile(token)
    elif selection_mode == "3":
        total_dirtycoins -= 150
        print("You bought a big token. Token stored in tokens.txt folder in your desktop")
        print(f"You have {total_dirtycoins} tokens left.")
        return openfile(token)
    else:
        print("Could not complete purchase. Permission denied. Error {0}")


# Layer 1: Select market

select_market = input("Select markets: Option 1: Generate tokens. Option 2: Buy tokens.\n")
if select_market == "1":
    token_generator()

elif select_market == "2":
    token_generator()
    f = open("C:\\Users\\mayan\\Desktop\\tokens.txt", "r")
    token = f.read()
    f.close()
    buy_tokens(token)

else:
    print("No market found, Permission denied.")
```

Comment: you are helping me alot, thank you very much, i hope you have a nice day <3